# backwards recursive printing in C

Tags: c

I'm trying out recursion and tried this exercise to print a word backwords. What am i doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void recursivePrint(char* x){

    if (*x = '\0')
        return;
    else
        recursivePrint(x++);
        printf("%c", *x);

}

int main()
{
    char x[10] = "Hello";

    recursivePrint(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1)`if (*x = '\0')` 2)`x++` ,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`=` is an assignment operator. And `==` is used for comparison.
Change

```
if (*x = '\0')
```

To

```
if (*x == '\0')
```

**EDIT:**

To see the first character,

Change

```
void recursivePrint(char* x){
    if (*x == '\0')
        return;
    else
        recursivePrint(x++);
    printf("%c", *x);
}
```

To

```
void recursivePrint(char* x){
    if (*x == '\0')
        return;
    else
        recursivePrint(x+1);
    printf("%c", *x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Dumb mistake, how can i change the logic to show the first character H? Since i'm incrementing the x.

Comment: @runners3431: first result means?

Comment: I'm getting this output " olle" instead of "olleH"

Comment: @runners3431 Well, don't increment `x`, then you'll see the first character. Just replace `recursivePrint(x++);` with `recursivePrint(x+1);`

Comment: Ok I get it, I need to be able to print the value of X.

Comment: @runners3431 It is generally a good exercise to draw the call stack. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the assignment that was meant to be a comparison (as pointed out in another answer), you shouldn't increment `x`, since you will want to output it after the recursive call. Incrementing `x` is unnecessary and as you can see is error-prone. What is happening is that the call number `i` is printing character `i+1`, so the second to last call is actually passing the null terminator to `printf()`; the third to last is passing the character before the NULL, etc. See it like this:

```
recursivePrint("Hello");
    recursivePrint("ello");
        recursivePrint("llo");
            recursivePrint("lo");
                recursivePrint("o");
                    recursivePrint("");
                        return;
                    /* x was incremented, points to \0 */
                    print '\0'
                /* x was incremented, points to "o" */
            /* ... */
```

So basically, you are always one character ahead of the one you want to print. You can fix it by passing `x[-1]` to `printf()`, but that is ugly. A better approach would be:

```
void recursivePrint(char *x) {
    if (*x == '\0')
        return;

    recursivePrint(x+1);
    printf("%c", *x);

}
```

This is better because you never wanted / needed to increment `x` in the first place.

Comment: Thank you Filipe! Makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
void recursivePrint(char* x){
    if (*x == '\0')
        return;
    recursivePrint(x+1);
    printf("%c", *x);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but some of the answers here are incorrect and generate segfaults.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void recursivePrint(const char *x) {
   if (*x == '\0') {
      return;
   }
   recursivePrint(x+1);
   printf("%c", *x);
}

int main(void) {
   const char* x = "Hello";
   recursivePrint(x);
   return 0;
}
```

You should really use `const char*` since your function doesn't modify the data.